# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException while run analysis on sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm constantly getting below error while running code analysis on sonarqube

Please help me to resolve it. Please find the Exception below;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.rethrowExecutionException(AdapterActionFuture.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:46)
at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyRefreshRequestBuilder.get(ProxyRefreshRequestBuilder.java:42)
at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyRefreshRequestBuilder.get(ProxyRefreshRequestBuilder.java:32)
at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:109)
at org.sonar.server.component.index.ComponentIndexer.delete(ComponentIndexer.java:117)
at org.sonar.server.computation.dbcleaner.IndexPurgeListener.onComponentsDisabling(IndexPurgeListener.java:44)
at org.sonar.db.purge.PurgeDao.purgeDisabledComponents(PurgeDao.java:143)
at org.sonar.db.purge.PurgeDao.purge(PurgeDao.java:73)
at org.sonar.server.computation.dbcleaner.ProjectCleaner.doPurge(ProjectCleaner.java:91)
at org.sonar.server.computation.dbcleaner.ProjectCleaner.purge(ProjectCleaner.java:64)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PurgeDatastoresStep.execute(PurgeDatastoresStep.java:78)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PurgeDatastoresStep.access$000(PurgeDatastoresStep.java:40)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PurgeDatastoresStep$1.visitProject(PurgeDatastoresStep.java:65)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitNode(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:70)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:51)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PurgeDatastoresStep.execute(PurgeDatastoresStep.java:72)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:92)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:59)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarQube

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved after I remove indexes of elastic search

Removed ${SONARQUBE-HOME}/data/es

and restart sonarqube server

it resolved problem